# Alert inside the custom alert show the error in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I use the following code to show the alert in android ,

after clicking yes i need to show the another alert ,

but i will show the error. The code i used is shown below,

```
    authalert.setTitle("Save Video");
    authalert.setMessage("Do you want to save this Video?");
    authalert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


     LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
                View forgotPasswordView =li.inflate(R.layout.forgotpopup, null);


   AlertDialog.Builder forgotPasswordBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
                forgotPasswordBuilder.setTitle("Forgot Password");
                forgotPasswordBuilder.setView(forgotPasswordView);
     final AlertDialog forgotPasswordDetail = forgotPasswordBuilder.create();
              forgotPasswordDetail.show();
                                   }
                                   });
```

the following error i got,

```
04-01 11:33:28.708: ERROR/global(3440): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-01 11:33:28.708: ERROR/global(3440):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
04-01 11:33:28.708: ERROR/global(3440):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
04-01 11:33:28.708: ERROR/global(3440):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
```

Anyone give some suggestion to recover this.

Comment: Did you step thru the code and find the offending function?

Comment: You should not use getBaseContext() (as per Android developers), try using getApplicationContext(). Also are you only seeing this exception in the logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Move the code 
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
                View forgotPasswordView =li.inflate(R.layout.forgotpopup, null);

AlertDialog.Builder forgotPasswordBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
                forgotPasswordBuilder.setTitle("Forgot Password");
                forgotPasswordBuilder.setView(forgotPasswordView);
     final AlertDialog forgotPasswordDetail = forgotPasswordBuilder.create();

to create() class, and call the forgotPasswordDetail.show() , inside the alert ,its working fine.